# Give permission based on the content type in SP 2013

Tags: permissions, content-type

My list contains 2-3 content types. And based on that content type i want to give permission to the user to access the list.Is it possible to set the permission based on  the content type??
If yes, then please expalin in detail.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions are associated with a list, list item but not with a content type. You can create an item of particular content type and that item can have different permissions. For example, you can have an event receiver attached to a content type or a list and once item is created/updated the permissions associated with it can be changed. See this [SP 2010, Is it possible to set permissions at Content Type Level](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19398/sp-2010-is-it-possible-to-set-permissions-at-content-type-level)