# Document Library Content Type Restriction

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, content-type, custom-permission-level

I have a Document Library with 3 different content types that require different properties for each.
When uploading a document users select which document type they are uploading and then fill out the appropriate properties.

I am trying to restrict permissions so that normal users can only select 2 of the 3  content Types and the 3rd is restricted to site Owners only.

Normal users should still be able to see the 3rd content type just not upload it

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not achievable with OOB solutions since SharePoint doesn’t support permission on content types.

I am thinking about Event Receiver as well.

This is similar to restriction on file types uploaded to a document library, but actually based on content types.

Some references for you:

[Restrict File Types in SharePoint Document Library Upload using Event Receiver.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/07/restrict-file-types-in-document-library-event-receiver.html)

[SP 2010, Is it possible to set permissions at Content Type Level.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19398/sp-2010-is-it-possible-to-set-permissions-at-content-type-level)

[Powershell - Item Level Permission by Content Type.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19771/powershell-item-level-permission-by-content-type)

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint permissions are worked on list level or item level... and item gets created through the content type.... so if you want to alter any permission you need to handle this through event receiver or workflow after the item added.

Reference URL : [Give permission based on the content type in SP 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132909/give-permission-based-on-the-content-type-in-sp-2013)

If you want to handle the permission based on the content type... we need to handle this thru the third party document classification Metadata security by TITUS:

Reference URL :
https://sharepointmetadataandclassification.typepad.com/blog/2009/09/sharepoint-security-based-on-content-type-.html